# S3 with Cloudfront SignedURL

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to **Node.js** and currently using [aws-cloudfront-sign](https://github.com/jasonsims/aws-cloudfront-sign) package. It is working on public buckets. But when I am using private folders, it said Access Denied.

```
var cf = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');
var options = {
  keypairId: KEY,
  privateKeyPath: PATHTOPEMFILE
};

cf.getSignedUrl(CLOUDFRONTURL + directory + file, options);
```

It return a signedURL but showing Access Denied. What am I doing wrong? Or, is there any other way for S3 with Cloudfront SignedURL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you maybe confusing [signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) with [origin access identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).  Based on your description, it sounds like S3 is returning access denied to CloudFront because the folder/bucket is private.  I would recommend taking a look at the documentation on configuring [origin access identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html), OAI.

- Create OAI
- Associate OAI with distribution
- Update S3 bucket policy to grant GetObject to OAI